# How do I extract multiple numbers from a string?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, extract

I want to extract three doubles from this string.  The is a space between the numbers but nothing else.

string A = "3.1415 2.71828 1729.0"

Comment: What have u tried? u can use `String.Split(' ');` and then can convert to Double

Comment: You can split by ` ` (space) and typecast to `float`/`double` or use regex. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The split function worked.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try this **A.Split(' ').Select(Double.Parse).ToList()**

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Split()` method.

```
string[] nums = A.Split(' ');
```

Then do the conversion.

Updated:
Changed double quotes to single quotes

Comment: This will not compile. No such overload exists.

Comment: I updated the code. Changed " "  to ' '. Now it will compile.

Comment: For this problem you don't have to use Split(' '), you can use Split() without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the String.Split() method combined with LINQ:

```
string A = "3.1415 2.71828 1729.0";
double[] numbers = A.Split().Select(x=>double.Parse(x.Replace(".",","))).ToArray();
```

In the above example the decimal numbers in string `A` are converted from `string` to `double` and stored in a double array, but if you want to store your decimal numbers as separate strings in a string array then use:

```
string[] numbers = A.Split();
```